# In Flutter show image form gallery or from network in same view

Tags: flutter, networkimageview, image-file

I am selecting on image from gallery then uploading it on server, after that on successful upload i am hitting one API to retrieve same image from server and want to show that image in the same ImageView I am using **Image.file** To load clicked image and  **Image.network** To show Network image but i want One single thing to load image

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: just set a boolen isImageUploaded, if it is true show Image.network widget else Image.asset image

Comment: i need one single function to load image, is there any library for this?

Comment: in android studio we have picasso and Glide like that same library in flutter?

Comment: try cachedImageNetwork, when url fails you can set from File

Comment: sorry but what i need is library or function to show image from URI and URL both in One

Comment: Right now i am doing this --  child: _imageFile == null? Image.asset( 'assets/images/placeholder.png',) : Image.file(_imageFile),

Answer (score 2):

Try this, just set an boolen **isProfileImageIsURL**, if it is true show NetworkImage widget else FileImage

```
isProfileImageIsURL ? NetworkImage(profileImageURL) : FileImage(_profilePictureFile);
```

Comment: that's what i have replied above on your comment, i am using the same condition but i need single image loader for both the operations

Comment: else load image from url and covert ad an file, then use in FileImage.

Comment: thanks for the reply as i am using ternary operator only in my code.